# Get a respective cell value from a row when drop down list selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table generated dynamically

[image]

**Codes as below**

```html
echo '
<tr>
  <td scope="row">'.$srNumberOa.'</td>
  <td>'.$check.'</td>
  <td>'.$numberOfDays.'</td>
  <td>'.$uph.'</td>
  <td>'.$numberOfUsefulHoursPerOa.'</td>
  <td>'.$numberOfPinsPerOa.'</td>
  <td>

    <div class="col-sm" id="">
      <select class="form-control" id="" name="">
        <option selected="selected"> </option>
        <option>Shift 1</option>
        <option>Shift 2</option>
        <option>Shift 3</option>
        <option>Shift 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>


  </td>

  <td>

    <input type="radio" name="currentOa">

  </td>
</tr>';
```

Here all those are dynamic php variables inside the `<td>` tag.

I want to alert or capture the value of 'Name' and respective radio button status when the respective 'OA Shift' dropdown list selected. For example, if I change the 'OA Shift' drop down list of serial No: 11th row, it should alert or capture Name as X and radio button as false. Can someone help me how to do it?

**Edit 1**

Please take note that, the form that I showed above is an Ajax output. So all these values are coming from another php page.

Comment: can you give these td a unique id

Comment: I will try that way too. Will update if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, this is done by firing the desired event handler on the `select`-element, from there on, finding the one of `parents()` that is the current row (`<tr>`), then finding the child containing the name and the respective radio button in this row:

https://codepen.io/shikifujin/pen/xxbZgqx

The alert in this example is triggered when you select one element in the dropdown list of the `select` input (`'change'` event).

The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$("select.form-control").on("focus", function() {
  var rowName = $(this)
    .parents("tr")
    .children("td:nth-child(2)")
    .text();
  var rowRadio = $(this)
    .parents("tr")
    .find('input[name="currentOa"]')
    .is(":checked");
  alert(
    "Name: " + rowName + " currentOa checked: " + (rowRadio ? "yes" : "no")
  );
});
```

For getting the row's current values, your HTML code doesn't provide any good selectors. The column containing the name is the 2nd td-child (`td:nth-child(2)`) - would be better if it was tagged with a class (e.g., `<td class="col-name"` or something alike).
The radio button's current value in this row is not exactly on the children's level, so it is found by using `.find('input[name="currentOa"]')` traversing the DOM below the row. Its current status is returned applying the `.is(':checked')`.

Then, you can do whatever you like with the `rowName` and `rowRadio` values, instead of alerting them.

**Edit:**

I updated my example at https://codepen.io/shikifujin/pen/xxbZgqx to do AJAX (wrapping the above jQuery code in a function `onAfterAJAX`). When clicking the button, the `<tr>`s are requested from another Pen via `$.ajax()` and appended to the table:

```
$("button#ajax").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://codepen.io/shikifujin/pen/dyPGJBq.html",
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      $("table").append(data);
      onAfterAJAX();
    }
  });
});
```

The reason why it didn't work before was because it took place in this order:

1. The DOM of your page with an either pre-filled or empty table was loaded,
2. then the jQuery for all `select.form-control` fired.
3. Next, your page probably requested the content via AJAX and added it to the page.

But at 3., the jQuery function adding the change-handler was already through and done. Now, the wrapper function `onAfterAJAX` is to be executed whenever a successful AJAX request comes back, applying the handler on newly added elements.

To prevent multiple events to be added to previously existing rows, I prepended an `.off('change')` to the change handlers getting rid of any previously added handlers. That means, this both works for replacing, as well as replacing content.

Comment: As I mentioned to others, your code is working fine when run independently. But the table that I mentioned is an Ajax output and thus when I gave the JQuery code you gave in the output page, it is not working. Any work around for that problem?

Comment: I updated my example to do AJAX. Depending on how exactly you're using AJAX, you just have to make sure the wrapper function executes **after** the content is added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

As you use jquery - you can add an `change` handler for your select:

```js
$('select.form-control').on('change', function() {
    // find the parent `tr` for the `select`
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    // `name` is the text of second `td`:
    var name = tr.find('td').eq(1).text();
    alert(name);
    // checkbox can be found by "name" attribute, for example:
    var cb = tr.find('input[name="currentOa"]');
    alert(cb.prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td scope="row">11</td>
  <td>X</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>
  <div class="col-sm" id="">
      <select class="form-control" id="" name="">
        <option selected="selected"> </option>
        <option>Shift 1</option>
        <option>Shift 2</option>
        <option>Shift 3</option>
        <option>Shift 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>


  </td>

  <td>

    <input type="radio" name="currentOa">

  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td scope="row">22</td>
  <td>Y</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>
  <div class="col-sm" id="">
      <select class="form-control" id="" name="">
        <option selected="selected"> </option>
        <option>Shift 1</option>
        <option>Shift 2</option>
        <option>Shift 3</option>
        <option>Shift 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>


  </td>

  <td>

    <input type="radio" name="currentOa">

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just updated my question. I forgot to mention that, this table is an Ajax output. I tried your code in my output page, but it is not working. But when I tried your code as stand alone, it is working. Do you know why that way?

Comment: If table is dynamically generated try to bind listener as `$(document).on('change', 'select.form-control',  function() {`

Comment: Can we select based on id? The `select.form-control` is interfering with other forms in the output page

Comment: `id` is a __unique__ identificator. Add some class instead.

Comment: Somehow when I replaced `$('select.form-control').on('change', function() {`  with `$(document).on('change', 'select.form-control', function() {` some other JQuery behaviour of the form lost. Also I added another class `shiftSelector` in addition to `form-control`. So actual code I type is `$(document).on('change', 'select.shiftSelector', function() {`

Answer (score 1):

Following code can be used to achieve the above goal:

```js
$('select.select-dropdown').on('change', function() {
  var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
  var radioStatus = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked');
  alert("Name: " + name + "::" + "select value: " + $(this).val() + "::" + "Radio Status: " + radioStatus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flag" /></td>
    <td>
      <select class="select-dropdown">
        <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
        <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="flag" /></td>
    <td>
      <select class="select-dropdown">
        <option value="4">Opt 4</option>
        <option value="5">Opt 5</option>
        <option value="6">Opt 6</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zvp5L73t/1/) is a JSFiddle link for the same.

Comment: I just updated my question. I forgot to mention that, this table is an Ajax output. I tried your code in my output page, but it is not working. But when I tried your code as stand alone, it is working. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I have no idea of how your current code looks like. You might wanna write this code where you get the status of `complete`. For reference, read [this link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) thoroughly.